# how to remove the quotation mark in string

Tags: haskell

I'm really new in Haskell. perhaps this is a simple question for the master coder. I want to remove the quotation mark outside the string. such as "A1" to A1.

I tried my best to solve this problem. but it doesn't work. I already used read :: Read a => String -> a, id function, and  regular expression.

```
initialGuess :: ([Pitch],GameState)
initialGuess = (startGuess, GameState (chords))
      where startGuess = ["A1", "B1", "C1"] 
      standard = [[n, o] | n <- ['A'..'G'], o <- ['1'..'3']]  <br/>
      chords = [[a,b,c] | a <- standard, b <- standard, c <-  
               standard, a /= b, b /= c, a /= c]
```

initialGuess aim to takes no input arguments.And returns a pair of an initial guess and a game state. Running this code I can get

> ["A1","B1","C1"],GameState [["A1","A2","A3"],["A1","A2","B1"],["A1","A2","B2"],["A1","A2","B3"],["A1","A2","C1"]................["A1","A2","C2"],["A1","A2","C3"],["A1","A2","D1"],["A1","A2","D2"],["A1","A2","D3"]]

however, I want to remove these quotation marks such as

> [A1,B1,C1],GameState [[A1,A2,A3],[A1,A2,B1],[A1,A2,B2],[A1,A2,B3],[A1,A2,C1]................[A1,A2,C2],[A1,A2,C3],[A1,A2,D1],[A1,A2,D2],[A1,A2,D3]]

Comment: How are you viewing the result? Are you viewing it via GHCi, or `show`ing it, or `print`ing it, or what? My guess is that GHC adds the quotes when it prints the value, as the default pretty-printing style for strings is that they are printed with quotes surrounding them.

Comment: Fixed some grammar. Added some layout to clarify output.

Comment: `Show` is intended for rendering a simple string representation of a value as a Haskell expression, which can be copied and pasted as Haskell code, or parsed using `Read`. That’s why `instance Show String` returns text with quote marks. It’s fine for basic testing and debugging, but if you want output formatted in a custom way, you should write custom functions producing strings formatted the way you want—which may of course use `Show` for basic things like numbers. For more complex formatting, there are libraries such as `pretty`, which also provides a `Pretty` typeclass for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If all you are trying to do is make the states prettier, you can provide your own display function:

```
-- |Display a list of strings without quotation marks
showLStr :: [String] -> String
showLStr p  = "[" ++ intercalate "," p ++ "]"
```

The `intercalate` function puts the `","` between each element of the list of strings.

```
showLStr ["A1", "A2", "A3"]
```

should display as

```
[A1,A2,A3]
```

Edit: Now you can use `showLStr` to display the game state:

```
showGameState :: GameState -> String
showGameState (GameState chords) =
  "GameState [" ++ (intercalate "," $ map showLStr chords) ++ "]"

-- |Make GameState "Show"-able
instance Show GameState where
  show = showGameState

showGuess :: ([Pitch],GameState) -> String
showGuess (pitch, gameState) = showLStr pitch ++ ", " ++ show gameState
```

Comment: this doesn't show *how to use* this function, to actually do what the OP asks for. they are " really new in Haskell".